# Can I debug download/network issues while using a standard ISO with debian-installer?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, system-installation, busybox, debian-installer

During the installation of e.g. Ubuntu with the debian-installer, is there any visible (debug) output, where I can see what is downloaded from where?

(I have a local mirror configured, but it is so slow that I want to investigate the situation.)

The problems are:

- the installer does neither show from where it downloads, nor the speed in it’s normal output
- in /var/log/syslog is constantly filled with status updates
- the pager `more` of busybox can’t scroll back nor search, so it is hard to tell if the installer even echoed the server before downloading a bunch of files
- `ps` does not reveal `wget` or any other download tool with arguments
- there is no `netstat` or `ntop` or similar installed
- I’m not sure where the files are downloaded, so I can’t not even make a download speed estimate with `ls -la` by watching some files grow

Comment: `CTL` + `ALT` + `F4` should show you the verbose output of the installation.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson, I know that. – But it does not reveal the details. Maybe too much flows through because of my `DEBCONF_DEBUG=5` kernel boot parameter?

Comment: @GAD3R And what do I do with the shell?; I can have a shell on virtual console 2 and 3 at any time.